# Preciso mostrar um conjunto de dados no MYSQL

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, mysqli, tabela-banco-de-dados

Preciso puxar a quantidade de partidas jogadas, quantidade de gols marcados, criar uma média de gol por partida (média de gols = Quantidade de partidas / Quantidade de gols) tudo em uma View,

Eu fiz a VIEW mas sempre puxa como se estivesse retornando mais de 1 Row, segue linha de programação.

```
    CREATE VIEW segunda AS
SELECT
    (SELECT count(partidas) FROM standings GROUP BY time_id) as partidas,
    (SELECT count(gols_a_favor) FROM standings GROUP BY time_id) as gols,
    ((SELECT count(partidas) FROM standings GROUP BY time_id) / (SELECT count(gols_a_favor) FROM standings GROUP BY time_id)) as Quantidade_de_gols,
    (SELECT max(gols_a_favor) FROM standings GROUP BY time_id) as time_mais_gols,
    (select max(gols_a_favor) FROM standings GROUP BY gols_a_favor) as gols_do_time_max
FROM
    partidas JOIN times AS primeiro_time JOIN standings AS standings;
```

e a programação completa:

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS `senai_copa`;
CREATE DATABASE `senai_copa`; 
USE `senai_copa`;

CREATE TABLE times (
    id INTEGER UNSIGNED auto_increment NOT NULL,
    pais CHARACTER VARYING(64) NOT NULL,
    tecnico CHARACTER VARYING(128) NOT NULL,
    nome_do_time ENUM("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H") NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE jogadores (
    id INTEGER UNSIGNED auto_increment NOT NULL,
    nome CHARACTER VARYING(128) NOT NULL,
    time_id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (time_id) REFERENCES times(id),
    PRIMARY KEY (id, time_id)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE estadios (
    id INTEGER UNSIGNED auto_increment NOT NULL,
    nome CHARACTER VARYING(32) NOT NULL,
    cidade CHARACTER VARYING(16) NOT NULL,
    publico INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE partidas (
    id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    primeiro_time INTEGER UNSIGNED NULL,
    segundo_time INTEGER UNSIGNED NULL,
    data INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    estadio INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (estadio) REFERENCES estadios(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (primeiro_time) REFERENCES times(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (segundo_time) REFERENCES times(id),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE gols (
    id INTEGER UNSIGNED auto_increment NOT NULL,
    jogo_id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    time_id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    jogador_id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    minuto INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    tempo INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    type ENUM("normal", "og", "penalty"),
    FOREIGN KEY (time_id) REFERENCES times(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (jogador_id) REFERENCES jogadores(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (jogo_id) REFERENCES partidas(id),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE cartaos (
    id INTEGER UNSIGNED auto_increment NOT NULL,
    jogo_id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    time_id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    jogador_id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    minuto INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    tempo INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    cartao ENUM("red", "yellow"),
    FOREIGN KEY (time_id) REFERENCES times(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (jogador_id) REFERENCES jogadores(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (jogo_id) REFERENCES partidas(id),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=INNODB;


CREATE VIEW primeira AS
SELECT
    partidas.id,
    partidas.data as data,
    publico,
    cartao as cartões,
    primeiro_time.id as primeiro_time_id,
    primeiro_time.pais as primeiro_time_pais,
    segundo_time.id as segundo_time_id,
    segundo_time.pais as segundo_time_pais,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM gols WHERE time_id = primeiro_time.id AND gols.jogo_id = partidas.id AND (type = "normal" || type = "penalty"))+(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM gols WHERE time_id = segundo_time.id AND gols.jogo_id = partidas.id AND type = "og") AS resultado_primeiro_time,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM gols WHERE time_id = segundo_time.id AND gols.jogo_id = partidas.id AND (type = "normal" || type = "penalty"))+(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM gols WHERE time_id = primeiro_time.id AND gols.jogo_id = partidas.id AND type = "og") AS resultado_segundo_time
FROM
    partidas JOIN times AS primeiro_time ON primeiro_time = primeiro_time.id JOIN times AS segundo_time ON segundo_time = segundo_time.id JOIN cartaos as cartão JOIN estadios as publico;


CREATE TABLE standings (
    time_id INTEGER UNSIGNED,
    partidas TINYINT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0,
    ganhas TINYINT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0,
    empate TINYINT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0,
    perdidas TINYINT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0,
    gols_a_favor INTEGER  DEFAULT 0,
    gols_Contra INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
    pontos TINYINT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0,
    PRIMARY KEY(time_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (time_id) REFERENCES times(id)
);

CREATE VIEW segunda AS
SELECT
    (SELECT count(partidas) FROM standings GROUP BY time_id) as partidas,
    (SELECT count(gols_a_favor) FROM standings GROUP BY time_id) as gols,
    ((SELECT count(partidas) FROM standings GROUP BY time_id) / (SELECT count(gols_a_favor) FROM standings GROUP BY time_id)) as Quantidade_de_gols,
    (SELECT max(gols_a_favor) FROM standings GROUP BY time_id) as time_mais_gols,
    (select max(gols_a_favor) FROM standings GROUP BY gols_a_favor) as gols_do_time_max
FROM
    partidas JOIN times AS primeiro_time JOIN standings AS standings;
```

Sempre ele retorna o erro 1242, subquery return more than 1 row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Sobre a View

> Preciso puxar a quantidade de partidas jogadas, quantidade de gols marcados, criar uma média de gol por partida (média de gols = Quantidade de partidas / Quantidade de gols) tudo em uma View

De acordo com sua estrutura do banco de dados, acredito que a `view` seguinte retorne o que você precisa:

```
create view partidas_gols as
Select
  (select count(*) from partidas) quantidade_de_partidas_jogadas,
  (Select count(*) from gols) quantidade_de_gols_marcados,
  ( (Select count(*) from gols) / (select count(*) from partidas)) as media_de_gols
```

Vale ressaltar que considerei que houve um equívoco quando você disse que precisava:

> criar uma média de gol por partida (média de gols = Quantidade de partidas / Quantidade de gols)

Dessa forma considerei que o certo seja:
**criar uma média de gol por partida** (média de gols = Quantidade de **gols** / Quantidade de **partidas** )

### Sobre o `erro 1242, SUBQUERY return more than 1 row`

O problema é que nas subconsultas não existe uma cláusula que faça com que o resultado da subconsulta retorne apenas uma linha.

Por exemplo, digamos que o comando  `SELECT * FROM standings` retorne:

| time_id | partidas | ganhas | empate | perdidas | gols_a_favor | gols_Contra | pontos |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 2 | 20 |
| 2 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 10 |

Na `view segunda` a subconsulta `(SELECT count(partidas) FROM standings GROUP BY time_id) as partidas` retornaria:
|count(partidas)|
|---------------|
|1|
|1|
Como no exemplo existem dois `time_id` distintos, a subconsulta está retornando como resultado a quantidade de linhas igual a quantidade de `time_id` distintos, no nosso exemplo são duas linhas.
Mas como essa subconsulta representa uma coluna do resultado, o Sistema Gerenciador do Banco de Dados (SGBD) espera que a subconsulta retorne apenas uma linha, como isso não está ocorrendo, o SGBD está informando o erro: `erro 1242, SUBQUERY return more than 1 row`.

**Para corrigir:**
Com base no seu comando

> ```
> CREATE VIEW segunda AS
> SELECT
>    (SELECT count(partidas) FROM standings GROUP BY time_id) as partidas,
>    (SELECT count(gols_a_favor) FROM standings GROUP BY time_id) as gols,
>    ((SELECT count(partidas) FROM standings GROUP BY time_id) / (SELECT > 
>     count(gols_a_favor) FROM standings GROUP BY time_id)) as Quantidade_de_gols,
>    (SELECT max(gols_a_favor) FROM standings GROUP BY time_id) as time_mais_gols,
>    (select max(gols_a_favor) FROM standings GROUP BY gols_a_favor) as > 
>     gols_do_time_max
> FROM
>    partidas JOIN times AS primeiro_time JOIN standings AS standings;
> ```

Uma opção é relaciona cada Subconsulta com a consulta principal de forma que o resultado da subconsulta seja único. Segue um exemplo que torna a consulta aceitável para o SGBD:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT count(partidas) FROM standings where time_id = partidas.primeiro_time GROUP BY time_id) as partidas,
    (SELECT count(gols_a_favor) FROM standings where time_id = partidas.primeiro_time GROUP BY time_id) as gols,
    ((SELECT count(partidas) FROM standings  where time_id = partidas.primeiro_time GROUP BY time_id) / (SELECT count(gols_a_favor) FROM standings  where time_id = partidas.primeiro_time  GROUP BY time_id)) as Quantidade_de_gols,
    (SELECT max(gols_a_favor) FROM standings  where time_id = partidas.primeiro_time GROUP BY time_id) as time_mais_gols,
    (select max(gols_a_favor) FROM standings  where time_id = partidas.primeiro_time GROUP BY gols_a_favor) as gols_do_time_max
FROM
    partidas 
   JOIN times AS primeiro_time on primeiro_time.id = partidas.primeiro_time 
   JOIN standings  on primeiro_time.id = standings.time_id ;
```

Observe que foi incluído o trecho `where time_id = partidas.primeiro_time` nas Subconsultas com o objetivo de ter apenas uma linha como resultado. Esta consulta acima é apenas para demonstrar uma possível correção do problema, pois os relacionamentos nos `joins` e a correlação entre a `consulta principal` e a `subconsultas` ficam a seu critério conforme suas necessidades.

### Dica

Para resolver esse tipo de erro, busque isolar as subcconsultas de forma que encontre aquela que está retornando mais de uma linha para poder adicionar critérios no comando que tornem seu resultado em uma linha conforme o SGBD espera.